# Kiwi TCMS Super user permissions from db

Tags: kiwi-tcms

We have a Kiwi TCMS installation in production using docker (as documented [here](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html))

Problem is there the person who installed it in the first place has left the company and was the Super User. So currently we have no Super User to manage the installation. Is there a way I can log into the db and make some changes to my username and make it super user? I have `root` access to the server where it is installed.

PS. I am not a `docker` guru in any way, so if you could include the instructions as well, that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I got it right. For anybody else who is stuck in a similar situation can follow the steps below. Before I go ahead, a fair warning: Steps below include editing entries in the database manually, be very careful what you do:

Access Kiwi Mariadb/MySQL database from CLI:

```
docker exec -it kiwi_db /usr/bin/mysql -uuser -ppass
```

View/select the database (named `kiwi` in my installation, will be the same in most of the cases):

```
MariaDB> show databases;
MariaDB> use kiwi;
```

(Optional) View who is the super user and who is not:

```
MariaDB> select username, is_superuser from auth_user;
```

Update the entry in `auth_user` table:

```
MariaDB> update auth_user set is_superuser=1 where username='your_user';
```

Check by logging into the Kiwi TCMS, `your_user` now should be the super user.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an interactive Python shell or DB shell directly like so:

```
docker exec -it kiwi_db /Kiwi/manage.py shell
docker exec -it kiwi_db /Kiwi/manage.py dbhell
```

The first one will configure Django and you can use the models directly, e.g.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
User.object.filter(username='someone-else').update(is_superuser=True)
```

You can also try `manage.py createsuperuser`.